# I want to obtain the output of GPS at every 5 secs and store them onto database using Arduino uno,GPS SKG 13BL and GSM module??

Tags: gsm, gps

I am on a project,in which I need to store the output of GPS from SKG 13BL to a database using Arduino UNO and GSM module.I wrote the following code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>
#include <NMEAGPS.h>

SoftwareSerial GSM(2, 3); // RX, TX: Connect TXD to RX & RXD to TX

static const int RXPin = 8, TXPin = 9;
AltSoftSerial gpsPort(RXPin, TXPin);
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

NMEAGPS gps;
gps_fix fix;
uint8_t fixCount = 0;
char dt[15],tm[15];

enum _parseState {
  PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE,

  PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO,

  PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE,
  PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT,
  PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH,

  PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH,
  PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT
};

enum _actionState {
  AS_IDLE,
  AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE
};

byte actionState = AS_IDLE;
unsigned long lastActionTime = 0;

byte parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
char buffer[80],url[80];
byte pos = 0;

int contentLength = 0;

void resetBuffer() {
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  pos = 0;
}

void sendGSM(const char* msg, int waitMs = 500) {
  GSM.println(msg);
  while(GSM.available()) {
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }
  delay(waitMs);
}

void setup()
{
  GSM.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gpsPort.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.println(F("GPS LOADING....."));
  Serial.println(F("Testing by : "));
  Serial.println(F("Billa"));
  Serial.println();

  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"vodafone\"");  
  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=1,1",3000);
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPINIT");  
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
}

void loop()
{ 
  unsigned long now = millis();

  while (gps.available( gpsPort )) {
    fix = gps.read();

    // Once every 5 seconds...    
    if (++fixCount >= 5) {
      displayInfo();
      fixCount = 0;
    }
  }

  if ((gps.statistics.chars < 10) && (millis() > 5000)) {
     Serial.println( F("No GPS detected: check wiring.") );
     while(true);
     block=1;
    }
  }

  if ( actionState == AS_IDLE ) {
    if ( now > lastActionTime + 5000 ) {
      sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://*****.000webhostapp.com/hinderset.php?date=%s\"", dt); // passing date only now as part of testing
      sendGSM(url);
      sendGSM("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
      lastActionTime = now;
      actionState = AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE;
    }
  }

  while(GSM.available()) {
    lastActionTime = now;
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }
}

void displayInfo()
{
  Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  if (fix.valid.location) {
    Serial.print( fix.latitude(), 5 );
    Serial.print( ',' );
    Serial.print( fix.longitude(), 5 );
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Speed: ")); 
  if (fix.valid.speed) {
    Serial.print(fix.speed_kph());
    Serial.print(F(" KMPH "));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  // Shift the date/time to local time
  NeoGPS::clock_t localSeconds;
  NeoGPS::time_t  localTime;
  if (fix.valid.date && fix.valid.time) {
    using namespace NeoGPS; // save a little typing below...

    localSeconds = (clock_t) fix.dateTime; // convert structure to a second count
    localSeconds += 5 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR + 30 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE; // shift timezone
    localTime = localSeconds;              // convert back to a structure
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Date : "));
  if (fix.valid.date) {
    sprintf(dt,"%02d/%02d/20%d",fix.dateTime.date,fix.dateTime.month,fix.dateTime.year);
    Serial.print(dt);
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Time : "));
  if (fix.valid.time) {
    if (localTime.hours>12)localTime.hours-=12;//To convert 24 hr format to 12 hr format
    sprintf(tm,"%02d:%02d:%02d",localTime.hours,localTime.minutes,localTime.seconds);
    Serial.print(tm);
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.println();
}

void parseATText(byte b) {

  buffer[pos++] = b;

  if ( pos >= sizeof(buffer) )
    resetBuffer(); // just to be safe

  /*
   // Detailed debugging
   Serial.println();
   Serial.print("state = ");
   Serial.println(state);
   Serial.print("b = ");
   Serial.println(b);
   Serial.print("pos = ");
   Serial.println(pos);
   Serial.print("buffer = ");
   Serial.println(buffer);*/

  switch (parseState) {
  case PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE: 
    {
      if ( b == '\n' )
        resetBuffer();
      else {        
        if ( pos == 3 && strcmp(buffer, "AT+") == 0 ) {
          parseState = PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO;
        }
        else if ( b == ':' ) {
          //Serial.print("Checking message type: ");
          //Serial.println(buffer);

          if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPACTION:") == 0 ) {
            Serial.println("Received HTTPACTION");
            parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE;
          }
          else if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPREAD:") == 0 ) {
            Serial.println("Received HTTPREAD");            
            parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH;
          }
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        Serial.print("Ignoring echo: ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE:
    {
      if ( b == ',' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION type is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT:
    {
      if ( b == ',' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION result is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION length is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);

        // now request content
        GSM.print("AT+HTTPREAD=0,");
        GSM.println(buffer);

        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        contentLength = atoi(buffer);
        Serial.print("HTTPREAD length is ");
        Serial.println(contentLength);

        Serial.print("HTTPREAD content: ");

        parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT:
    {
      // for this demo I'm just showing the content bytes in the serial monitor
      Serial.write(b);

      contentLength--;

      if ( contentLength <= 0 ) {

        // all content bytes have now been read

        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();

        Serial.print("\n\n\n");

        actionState = AS_IDLE;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

When I tested them in separate modules they worked and obtained result But now When I wrote the above code it is showing me "NO GPS DETECTED".Can you please help me in resolving the problem.The objective is I need to **obtain the output from GPS at every 5 secs** (5 secs interval between each output) and store them into database using GSM module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There are three problems:

**1)** You are using `delay`.

**2)** You are *still* using `SoftwareSerial`.  It blocks interrupts for long periods of time, interfering with other parts of your sketch.  I told you this in [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006844).

**3)** Starting the HTTP action is not synchronized with the GPS clock.  The Arduino `millis()` clock is not synchronized with the GPS atomic clock.  They will drift in and out of sync over time.  I also told you this in the same previous post.

#### The solution:

**1)** Don't use `delay`.  The GPS device continues to send characters, and they get dropped when the Arduino is blocked at the `delay`.

Instead, just send the command and let your nice `parseATTText` handle the response as it comes in, without waiting.  If there are multiple commands to send, add an extra state for each command.  When a response for the first command arrives, send the second command *and* step to the next state.

You can use `delay` in `setup` if you don't care about the responses to those initial commands.  Or you could add one SETUP_xxx state for each command to your FSM and let them happen in `loop`.  `parseATTText` will advance through those STARTUP states, sending each of those commands.

**2)**  Use [NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial).

**3)**  Move the HTTPPARA command into the GPS loop with `displayInfo`:

```
  while (gps.available( gpsPort )) {
    fix = gps.read();

    // Once every 5 seconds...    
    if (++fixCount >= 5) {
      displayInfo();

      // Send the next report if the previous one is finished
      if ( actionState == AS_IDLE ) {
        sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://*****.000webhostapp.com/hinderset.php?date=%s\"", dt); // passing date only now as part of testing
        sendGSM(url);
        parseState = PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE; // a new state
        actionState = AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE;
      }

      fixCount = 0;
    }
  }
```

You should move `sendGSM("AT+HTTPACTION=0")` into `parseATTText` as a `case PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE`, and step to the next state (PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE?)

If you reset `fixCount` inside the `if (actionState == IDLE)` block, it will send a new location when the previous one finally completes, perhaps after 6 new fixes.

Resetting  `fixCount` outside the block (as above) means it may send the 5th location, skip the 10th because it's NOT IDLE, and then send the 15th location.  If you want it to send the 5th, then the 11th if it's not busy, reset `fixCount` inside the `if` block.

Comment: it works fine.ty

Comment: I want to store the value of latitude and longitude onto a variable how can i do that.( here it just  prints Serial.print( fix.latitude(), 5 );
    Serial.print( ',' );
    Serial.print( fix.longitude(), 5 ); ) . I also want to store the speed to a variable how can i do that. when i used sprintf() it failed.

Comment: lat, lon and speed are *inside* the `fix` structure -- they are already variables.  A structure is just a "group" of variables.  In this case, `fix.latitude()` is a very simple function that returns the `fix.location._lat` variable as a `float` value.  Same with speed: `fix.speed_kph()` is a simple function that returns the `fix.spd...` variable's value, converted from knots to kph.  You can use `fix` (and its member variables) wherever you want, because it is a global, and it is always up-to-date.

Comment: If you *really* want a separate copy of the pieces inside `fix`, you can declare a second structure: `gps_fix oldFix;` and copy the current fix into it at some point:  `oldFix = fix; // save a snapshot`.

Comment: I use latitude and longitude for reverse geo and in this i require a precise value i.e about 4 decimal numbers ( like 9.7451 ) .when i use  
    Serial.print(fix.latitude);  it shows 9.74 .how can i get precise value.

Comment: `sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://masp203.000webhostapp.com/hinder.php?lat=%f&lng=%f&speed=%d&date=%s&time=%s\"",fix.latitude(),fix.longitude(),fix.speed_kph(),dt,tm );
      sendGSM(url);` When i use it like this it doent work.- `Location: 9.74511,76.71756  Speed: 0.15 KMPH   Date : 16/04/2017  Time : 09:12:38`-.for these values,in HTTPPARA lat,lng,speed and date value is not correct
`Ignoring echo: AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://masp203.000webhostapp.com/hinder.php?lat=?&lng=?&speed=-18622&date=&time=16/04/2017"`

Comment: You are using "speed=%d", but passing a floating-point `speed_kph()` value.  Either pass `(int)speed_kph()` or change the format specifier to "%f".  I assume you have enabled the "%f" specifier for the printf variants.